# DSO support routines and multiple OpenSSL load errors

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

I want to build an OpenSSL RSA engine, starting from [this existing source code file](http://fossies.org/linux/openssl/crypto/engine/eng_rsax.c) which is a faster method implemented by Intel. First of all I want to build this code so I'm using these commands:

```
gcc -fPIC -m64 -o eng_rsax.o -c eng_rsax.c
gcc -shared -o eng_rsax.so -lcrypto eng_rsax.o
```

... and no error shows up. Then, when I'm trying to test the engine by using the command:

```
openssl engine -t -c `pwd`/eng_rsax.so
```

... I receive the following errors:

```
140470207960736:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(/some_path/eng_rsax.so): /some_path/eng_rsax.so: undefined symbol: mod_exp_512
140470207960736:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
140470207960736:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:450:
140470207960736:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:417:id=/some_path/eng_rsax.so
```

At this point I guess I'm not using the right flags and maybe the commands for building the engine are incomplete.
What do I need to do in order to make this work?

Comment: It looks like its partially a path problem. Perhpas you can `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(pwd):LD_LIBRARY_PATH" openssl engine -t -c `pwd`/eng_rsax.so`

Comment: Thank you for commenting, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, I just implemented the body of `mod_exp_512` function at line 260 by adding `{}` instead of `;`. I used the same commands:

```
gcc -fPIC -m64 -o eng_rsax.o -c eng_rsax.c
gcc -shared -o eng_rsax.so -lcrypto eng_rsax.o
```